# Google Sheet query, slicer, and chart for dashboard

Tags: pivot, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table, dashboard, slicers

I hope i could find guidings on how i could make a better slicer for my dashboard. I'm still a beginner to advanced modern features like this. I have very basic knowledge and practice of SQL, and still very far from being able to put it to good use.

I've made an example table to showcase my idea of what kind of thing i'm trying to do
[image]
Google Sheet file: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NimQFg-5-7lQPQkUf-p9gIpbcRu8PxyehKB3jJJLR50/edit?usp=drive_link)

It features a table of statistic containing data of number of Hotels from a set of city, separated by City and Hotel star.

I want to make a dashboard that:

1. Consist of [stacked bar chart].
2. Two [slicer] that filters which city and stars i want to include.
3. I could [toggle axis] using a [drop down button].

[image: what i've done on the first sheet]

First sheet under the source table

---

[image]

Second sheet, meant as for dashboard page

---

My idea:

- make a separate query table to customize
- im hoping that the select to be able to match my cell range of criteria that could be toogled with slicer
- i hope that my slicer could work from separate sheet, but apparently it doesn't
- i also thought of making 2 separate table, one with pivot. the idea is to change the axis without having to go through edit charts > switch rows/columns thinking that i want the user to be more at ease when using the dashboard. perhaps i could make a workaround using dropdown box?

What i'm expecting:

- guidance for '"&()[]{} i don't know what to call it, so i can't search them by myself to learn about it
- guidance on how to make the kind of dashboard i'm hoping for, that could be very much easy to use even by technologically impaired user

Any kind of response are to be much appreciated, as i am very new to this kind of usage for google sheet. Thank you in advance <3